# How to get full page path with UTM params from google analytics reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

GA is stripping UTM params such as utm_source, utm_medium from pagePath dimension. Is there any way to get a full page path with all query string parameters without using ga:source, ga:medium dimensions?

I'm using analytics reporting API v4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to use those dimensions. If you want you can also use filters and apply them to the page path, but it will not retroactively add them back.